# redirect link with question mark in htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect:

```
example.com/wiki/?t=1234
```

to

```
example.com/vb/showthread.php?t=1234
```

The numbers "1234" is hundreds of pages with different numbers

I try in .htaccess but doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} t=[0-9]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vb/showthread.php?t=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} t=[0-9]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vb/showthread.php?t=$1 [L]
> ```

This will *match* the request, but won't redirect as intended (`$1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, not the query string). This is also an *internal rewrite*, not a "redirect" - as stated.

To *redirect* `/wiki/?t=1234` to `/vb/showthread.php?t=1234`, where `1234` is variable, then you should do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^wiki/$ /vb/showthread.php?t=%1 [R=302,L]
```

This matches the URL-path `/wiki/` and a query string that starts `t=` followed by 1 or more digits. The digits are captured by the regex `(\d+)`.

The `%1` backreference (note the `%`, not `$`) is a backreference to the captured group in the preceding *CondPattern*.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. But don't change this until you are sure it's working OK.

Comment: Great, this one work. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=(\d+) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vb/showthread.php?t=%1 [R=302,L] Thank you so much

Comment: By itself that would create a redirect loop. But I guess you must have other directives that prevent this.

Comment: If this helped answer your question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark below the voting arrows on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)